# Can not resolve integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I am doing an exercise about surface integral. I think that all my steps are good and that I am just blocking on the last step of the calculations, which is, if my steps are right,

$$
\int_0^1 u^2\sqrt{1+4u^2}\;du
$$

I don't figure out how to solve it, can someone help?

Comment: I would try the substitution $u=\dfrac12\sinh t$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Try the substitution: $$u=\frac{\tan(s)}{2}.$$